# If substring in string, remove it through the end from string

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following with javascript:
If a substring is in the string, remove from the beginning of the substring till the end of the string from the string.

For example (pseudocode):

```
var mySub = 'Foo'
var myString = 'testingFooMiscText'
var myString2 = 'testingMisctext'

var myStringEdit = //myString - (Foo till end myString)
var myString2Edit = myString2 //(cause no Foo in it)
```

Comment: So should the edited "testingFooMiscText" end up as "testing" or as "FooMiscText"?

Comment: @dmr To clarify, you would want `'testing'` from `myString`, correct?

Comment: So, if 'Foo' is in the string, you want to truncate the string starting at Foo? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Charmander is correct. I want to end up with `'testing'`

Comment: A super awesome tidbit for indexOf: Use ~ as invert: if(~index)
str = str.substr(index) -awesome read: http://timmywillison.com/pres/operators/#bitwise-operators - check out preceding slides for more context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var index = str.indexOf(str1);
if(index != -1)
    str = str.substr(index)
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand what you're asking, you'll want to do this:

```
function replaceIfSubstring(original, substr) {
    var idx = original.indexOf(substr);
    if (idx != -1) {
        return original.substr(idx);
    } else {
        return original;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Only truncates if substring in original, else returns original.

Answer (score 2):

If you want "testingFooMiscText" to end up as "testing", use

```
word = word.substring(0, word.indexOf("Foo"));
```

If you want "testingFooMiscText" to end up as "FooMiscText", use

```
word = word.substring(word.indexOf("Foo"));
```

You may need a +/- 1 after the indexOf() to adjust the start/end of the string

Answer (score 2):

```
myString.substring(0, myString.indexOf(mySub))
```

Comment: However, mySub might not be in myString...so then the substring function won't work.

Comment: Put it inside an if statement. Here is a question on checking to see if a string contains another. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Comment: This doesn't return the original string if the substring isn't found. I believe that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Fair enough, @FishBasketGordo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newString = mystring.substring(mystring.indexOf(mySub));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var myString = 'testingFooMiscText'
myString.substring(myString.indexOf('Foo'))  //FooMiscText
myString.substring(myString.indexOf('Bar'))  //testingFooMiscText
```

Answer (score -2):

I used following code to eliminate fakefile from file Name and it worked.

```
function confsel()
{
    val = document.frm1.fileA.value;
    value of val comes like C:\fakepath\fileName
    var n = val.includes("fakepath");
    if(n)
    {
        val=val.substring(12);
    } 
}
```